# How do you stop running server of Node.js (Express) in Hyper Terminal

Tags: node.js, express, server, terminal, nodemon

When I quit hyper terminal while running a server (port: 1000) (based on Express.js) that was started with nodemon, and reopen the hyper terminal and try to start the server (port: 1000) with/without nodemon again, this error below occurs. I'm not sure if it's caused by hyper terminal or nodemon.

I simply would like to know why the server is still running even though I have already quit the terminal, and how to force stop the server after I reopen the terminal.

```
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: listen EADDRINUSE: address already in use :::1000
    at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js...

(---snipped---)

  code: 'EADDRINUSE',
  errno: -48,
  syscall: 'listen',
  address: '::',
  port: 1000
}
[nodemon] app crashed - waiting for file changes before starting...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nodemon is designed to restart the node app when it detects a crash and so it probably restarted when you left the terminal session.

To force stop the nodemon process run:

```
sudo ss -lnp | grep 1000
```

This list all processes listening on port 1000

Note the pid i.e.

```
pid=27027
```

Then run:

```
sudo kill -9 27027
```